# Getting the src of an img tag on radio select

Tags: jquery, html

I have some HTML code as follows:

```
<div id="input-option227">
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="option[227]" value="17" />
            <img src="http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/canon_eos_5d_1-50x50.jpg" alt="black" class="img-thumbnail" />
            black
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="radio">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="option[227]" value="18" />
            <img src="http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/apple_logo-50x50.jpg" alt="green" class="img-thumbnail" />
            green
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the `img src` when I select the radio button means when the radio value is 17 then I want to alert:

`http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/canon_eos_5d_1-50x50.jpg`

and when the value is 18 then the alert should be:

`http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/apple_logo-50x50.jpg`

What I have done so far is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name="option[227]"]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '17') {
            alert('type A');
        }
        if ($(this).val() == '18') {
            alert('type B');
        }
    });
});
```

What should I do ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please have a look at this code snippet. I used `$.closest` and `$.find` to locate `img` tag associated with radio button.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function() {
        var closestLable = $(this).closest("label");
        var imgTag =  closestLable.find("img.img-thumbnail");
        var src = imgTag.attr("src");
        alert(src);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input-option227">
                                <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[227]" value="17" />
                    <img src="http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/canon_eos_5d_1-50x50.jpg" alt="black" class="img-thumbnail" /> black                                      </label>
                </div>
                                <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="option[227]" value="18" />
                    <img src="http://localhost/upload/image/cache/catalog/demo/apple_logo-50x50.jpg" alt="green" class="img-thumbnail" /> green                                      </label>
                </div>
                              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

clicked radio buttons are previous sibling of images which you want to target. You can use `.next()` selector along with clicked radio button context to target the image
:

```
$('input:radio[name="option[227]"]').change(function() {
    alert($(this).next().attr('src'));
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xabm35bh/)**

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 jQuery('input:radio[name="option[227]"]').change(function() {
        alert($(this).next().attr('src'));
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('input:radio').change(function () {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        alert($(this).siblings('.img-thumbnail').attr('src'));
    }
});
```

Use siblings selector and use the class of the image to select

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b2ezLg98/1/)